# 404 errors problem with multilangual permalink pages

Tags: slug, plugin-qtranslate

I am suffering an unexpected issue with [“Plugin: Qtranslate Slug”](https://github.com/not-only-code/qtranslate-slug); Some of my pages will automatically redirected to 404 error page. I tried a lot of this in slug but the issue is not resolved. This error mostly occurred on child pages.

In terms of solving the problem I need to remove database field value which holding slug value. After remove column values page working fine.

Can anyone please help me to override this problem; it’s very urgent?
I also found an issue on a forum ” https://wordpress.org/support/topic/404-errors-and-problem-with-child-pages/ ”

I  to dig for solutions for that and I found when I requested for a page with language slug plugin hook for ‘request’, getting post_type = ‘attachment’. But this is not right because I am requesting for ‘page’.

```
add_filter(‘request’, array(&$this, ‘filter_request’));
```

Comment: Share Site URL so we can check the issue

Comment: Site is under development stage.